# Display lines containing duplicates within subset of string

Tags: string, bash, duplicates

How would I find duplicate lines by matching only one part of each line and not the whole line itself?

Take for example the following text:

```
uid=154163(j154163) gid=10003(pemcln) groups=10003(pemcln) j154163
uid=152084(k152084) gid=10003(pemcln) groups=10003(pemcln) k152084
uid=154163(b153999) gid=10003(pemcln) groups=10003(pemcln) b153999
uid=154226(u154226) gid=10003(pemcln) groups=10003(pemcln) u154226
```

I would like to show only the 1st and 3rd lines only as the have the same duplicate UID value "154163"

The only ways I know how would match the whole line and not the subset of each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks for the ID from each line.  If any ID appears more than once, its lines are printed:

```
$ awk -F'[=(]' '{cnt[$2]++;lines[$2]=lines[$2]"\n"$0} END{for (k in cnt){if (cnt[k]>1)print lines[k]}}' file

uid=154163(j154163) gid=10003(pemcln) groups=10003(pemcln) j154163
uid=154163(b153999) gid=10003(pemcln) groups=10003(pemcln) b153999
```

#### How it works:

- `-F'[=(]'`

  `awk` separates input files into records (lines) and separates the records into fields.  Here, we tell `awk` to use either `=` or `(` as the field separator.  This is done so that the second field is the ID.
- `cnt[$2]++; lines[$2]=lines[$2]"\n"$0`

  For every line that is read in, we keep a count, `cnt`, of how many times that ID has appeared.  Also, we save all the lines associated with that ID in the array `lines`.
- `END{for (k in cnt){if (cnt[k]>1)print lines[k]}}`

  After we reach the end of the file, we go through each observed ID and, if it appeared more than once, its lines are printed.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explaining the answer, it helped greatly!

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already provided an `awk` script that will do what you need, assuming the files are small enough to fit into memory (they store all the lines until the end *then* decide what to output). There's nothing wrong with it, indeed it could be considered the canonical `awk` solution to this problem. I provide this answer really for those cases where `awk` may struggle with the storage requirements.

Specifically, if you have larger files that cause problems with that approach, the following `awk` script, `myawkscript.awk`, will handle it, provided you first sort the file so it can rely on the fact related lines are together. In order to ensure it's sorted and that you can easily get at the relevant key (using `=` and `(` as field separators), you call it with:

```
sort <inputfile | awk -F'[=(]' -f myawkscript.awk
```

The script is:

```
state == 0 {
    if (lastkey == $2) {
        printf "%s", lastrec;
        print;
        state = 1;
    };
    lastkey = $2;
    lastrec = $0"\n";
    next;
}
state == 1 {
    if (lastkey == $2) {
        print;
    } else {
        lastkey = $2;
        lastrec = $0"\n";
        state = 0;
    }
}
```

It's basically a state machine where state zero is scanning for duplicates and state one is outputting the duplicates.

In state zero, the relevant part of the current line is checked against the previous and, if there's a match, it outputs both and switches to state one. If there's no match, it simply moves on to the next line.

In state one, it checks each line against the original in the set and outputs it as long as it matches. When it finds one that doesn't match, it stores it and reverts to state zero.